# Google Visulisation scatter graph only showing last series tooltips

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

A demo is worth a thousand words: http://jsfiddle.net/5YEDW/2/

As you can see it's only the third series, the yellow one, that shows the tooltip. My understanding is that the code should work fine - as demonstrated in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ebyfc/

Any ideas why it is only showing the last series tooltip (in the first demo)?

To be clear, the red and blue markers should show the set tooltip, not the default. ie (00:15) not 10/2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need a tooltip column for each series.

http://jsfiddle.net/4THAe/1/