# create a custom info window in google scatter

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, scatter-plot

I have a google scatter, and I would like when mouse is over on circle  then open a info window containing a custom string.

for example in tutorial  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#Event_Listeners
when click on circle open a info window with a custom string.

Thanks

EDIT:

I try this code:

```
function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'SVD1');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'SVD2');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'SVD3');
  // A column for custom tooltip content
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    [2010, 600, null ,'test1'],
    [2011, 1500, null , 'test2'],
    [2012, null, 800, 'test3'],
    [2013, null, 1000, 'test4']
  ]);

  var options = {
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none'
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

Using tooltip the Strings "test 3" and "test4" appear right. The string "test1" and " "test2" disappear.  Why???

Comment: Do you want to change the tooltip, or do you want to spawn a completely different info window?

Comment: I want appear different String into infowindow.

Comment: Would a [tooltip column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole) work for you?

Comment: Yes, can I have an example of this? Please the chart will be scatter!
Thank you!

Comment: I try the tooltip and it is ok. But I have a different problem now. See the edit.

Comment: Find the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025988/google-visulisation-scatter-graph-only-showing-last-series-tooltips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!!! Βelow give a solution to the problem.

Sample Code:

```
function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'SVD1');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'SVD2');
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'SVD3');
  // A column for custom tooltip content
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    [2010,  600, 'test1' ,null, null],
    [2011, 1500, 'test2' ,null, null ],
    [2012, null, null, 800, 'test3'],
    [2013, null, null, 1000, 'test4']
  ]);

  var options = {
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none'
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```